# Spray JSON: Flexibility Array/Object

Tags: json, scala, json-deserialization, spray-json

Using Spray JSON, I would like to be able to parse an array of String, but still be able to deserialize correctly if a single String comes. 
That is, with this field:

```
arrayval: List[String]
```

and this JSON:

```
arrayval: ["a", "b"]
```

it would create a List("a","b"), and with this JSON:

```
arrayval: "a"
```

it would create a List("a").
Using default listFormat it would complain in the second case. 
Is there a way to configure this kind of flexibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, I've solved it by overriding the listFormat in the CollectionFormats (which is used in the DefaultJsonProtocol).

```
trait FlexibleCollectionFormats extends CollectionFormats {

  implicit override def listFormat[T: JsonFormat] = new RootJsonFormat[List[T]] {
    import spray.json._

    def write(list: List[T]) = JsArray(list.map(_.toJson).toVector)
    def read(value: JsValue): List[T] = value match {
      case JsArray(elements) => elements.map(_.convertTo[T])(collection.breakOut)
      case JsString(element) => List[T](new JsString(element).convertTo[T]) 
      case x                 => deserializationError("Expected List as JsArray, but got " + x)
    }
  }
}
```

Then I created my own protocol instead of DefaultJsonProtocol, that basically uses the same ones as Default but overriding the CollectionFormats:

```
trait FlexibleDefaultJsonProtocol
        extends BasicFormats
        with StandardFormats
        // with CollectionFormats
        with FlexibleCollectionFormats
        with ProductFormats
        with AdditionalFormats

object FlexibleDefaultJsonProtocol extends FlexibleDefaultJsonProtocol
```

and later you use `extends FlexibleDefaultJsonProtocol` instead of DefaultJsonProtocol. You can always switch and use one or the other in your classes, so I like the flex it provides.